# Disabled Trigger Re-Enabled After ALTER..How so?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

I have a trigger on one of my tables that has been disabled for some time.  I ran an ALTER to it to tweak some code for future reference when I realized the trigger had been re-enabled.  This happened on multiple environments regarding the same trigger.  My question for you all:  How is it possible for a disabled trigger to get re-enabled without manually doing it in Object Explorer or running an ENABLE script to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the trigger again after an alter.

Per the [disable trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/disable-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) doc:

> Changing the trigger by using the ALTER TRIGGER statement enables the trigger.

Comment: So I thought this was the case however, I tested it on my local instance and altering a disabled trigger did not enable it.

Comment: @Stack0verFlowSOS Did you refresh the folder afterwards?

Comment: I did.  I am using 2017 so Im curious if there is a difference between the versions.  It was my understanding too that in order to enable or disable with an ALTER you would have to specify ENABLE or DISABLE trigger within the statement.

Comment: @Stack0verFlowSOS If that's the case, they updated the alter = automatic enable behavior in 2017 but didn't document it.  I don't have a 2017 environment to test it but I'll take your word for it.  I'm confused though, how did you come across the alter = enable behavior to ask about it if the issue doesn't happen for you?

Comment: Well, the incident occurred in a 2012 environment but I tried to replicate it in a local environment due to bureaucracy regard the 2012 instance.  I am going to create a safe test site on that environment and try this there to see if Im noticing any differences.  

I highly doubt MS forgot to document a change like that if it was the case haha.  Ill keep you posted on my findings.  Thanks man!

Comment: Hey man, so I replicated this in one of our 2012 dev environments and then applied the concept to a 2017 environment back to back and it appears that in 2012 the ALTER  does indeed ENABLE the the trigger while in 2017 it does NOT.  

I guess it was an undocumented change...

Comment: @Stack0verFlowSOS That's really interesting, thanks for testing and sharing.  Now I really wish I knew someone on the Microsoft SQL team to berate them for their bad documentation :)